# How to download preview files from iTunes without installing iTunes software

Tags: windows, itunes, music

Is it possible to download music preview files from iTunes without installing iTunes software? I've read that it slows down your system a lot.

Is there any kind of script, portable tool or website that would just export the file links?

Example link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/a-higher-calling/id76156183

Comment: Unless someone manages to reverse-engineer how Apple does authentication and stuff (since they are paid tracks you also need to buy them using an account), **no, it's not possible.**

Comment: As a workaround you could run iTunes inside a virtual machine. This way you don't need to have it installed on your main system.